# Preview in TextMate html created by ruby script

Tags: script, html, textmate, preview

If I create ruby (or maybe not ruby, no difference) script in TextMate which produces html, is there an easy way to preview it using combination like `⌘R` or using Web Preview?

Now I found two ways to preview html: using [bcat](http://rtomayko.github.com/bcat/) — `ruby script.rb | bcat`, but I need to close browser tab every time and rerun script, or running this script on a web server, but this way is also not easy one.